# Msix, packaging and task scheduler

Tags: c#, msix

I made a console app using .NET 5.0 in VS2019 pro preview , packaged it with "Windows application packaging project" msix. Everything going smoothly and installed correctly, updates perfectly. Problem arises when I want to add this program to a task scheduler as the .exe file is located in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PackageName\Version...
 1. Can't run it from the WindowsApps folder due to restrictions (As there are going to be multiple other users it's not feasible to make them all gain access).
 2. The folder will change name if I push an update given the version nr.
Is there a way to do this correctly? Like a command to launch windows app files? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried defining an [execution alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#alias) and specifying the alias name (not path) as target for the scheduled task?

This should solve both the permission and changing paths problem.